# Error in Importing a bash script into a python

Tags: python, bash

I am trying to create a python script `script.py` in bash and importing a bash script.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python    
import os
import glob
from fnmatch import fnmatch
# importing a software
python_package = os.system("""#!/path_to_bin/bin/python \
from __future__ import print_function, division \
from python_toolbox.toolbox.some_toolbox import run \
if __name__ == '__main__': \
    run()"""

# testing 
greeting = "Hello world!"
print(greeting)
```

Running the `script.py` in python3

```
$python3 script.py
  File "script.py", line 15
    greeting = "Hello world!"
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: This is python running python... no bash.

Comment: Thanks @tdelaney, why there is a syntax error then?

Comment: Um... `os.system(...` has no closing paren.  It's best to read your own code before asking others to read it for you.

Comment: You are missing a paren at the end of your `os.system(... ` call. Python figured that out on the next line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nominally the problem is that you are missing the closing paren on the os.system call. But there is a better way to run a python program than trying to write it all on the command line. Instead, you can pass a full script, including newlines, to python's stdin.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python    
import sys
import subprocess as subp

# importing a software
def run_script():
    subp.run([sys.executable, "-"], input=b"""
print("I am a called python script")
""")

# testing
run_script() 
greeting = "Hello world!"
print(greeting)
```

In this script, the second python script is run whenever you call `run_script`. Notice that the script in the string has to follow the normal python indendation rules. So, there is indentation inside `run_script` but then the string holding the second script starts its indentation all the way to the left again.

Comment: Thank you very much @tdelaney. How do I call the software later in the code? I assigned the software into a variable like this: `variable = subp.run([sys.executable, "-"], input=b"""
print("I am a called python script")
""")`. But seems doesn't work.

Comment: That ran the script and saved `run` 's return value to `variable`. Instead you could write a function. I updated the example to do that.